# Remove/Hide all "text-decoration: line-through" formatted elements on a Website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting, strikethrough

How to remove or hide all elements on a webpage when text is formatted with: text-decoration: line-through?

Because these elements are already obsolete or just for reference, i don't want to see them anymore.

```html
<s>hide this line</s>
```

The solution should be universal and work for nearly every website., that means blocking them by class name is not the solution i prefer. Never the less, i'm open for every solution that works, JS, CSS, Browser setting, others ...

Any ideas how to solve this?

I've an approach with Tampermonkey but, this just helps to remove the strike out lines, not the element itself.

```
GM_addStyle('* { text-decoration: none !important; }');
```

I want something like that in the Pseudo code:

```
if (element.text-decoration == line-through) then
  element.remove
```

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: Please still need held into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a solution by myself, unfortunately it was a hard way for me due to lack knowledge into Web technologies, JS, CSS.
Now i use the Browser Plugin Tampermonkey to load user scripts into Browser.

Here the script-code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove strikethrough text
// @version      1.0
// @description  Removes all elements where 'text-decoration' == 'line-through'
// @author       CK
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  var elemStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elems[i]);
  if(elemStyle.getPropertyValue('text-decoration').startsWith('line-through',0)) {
    elems[i].remove();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is add the line below in your CSS.

```
s {
    display: none;
  }
```

Comment: 1) I have no control over the Server side CSS file. So just client side solution is possible

2) The element which is strikethrough could have any name, not just "s" like in the example.